# How can I best mentally calculate the total sum of a sequence of linear increases?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, mental-arithmetic

I often run into the following situation:

- In January, I'm producing $10$ items/month.
- By December, I want to be producing $65$ items/month.
- So assuming things improve linearly, my production is increasing by $5$ items/month.
- Question: How many total items do I produce during the year?

I could be wrong, but I think this can be represented like this:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N{a+\frac{n \cdot (z - a)}{N-1}}=\sum_{n=1}^{12}{10+\frac{n \cdot (65 - 10)}{12-1}}=\sum_{n=1}^{12}{10+5n}$$

I want to be able to roughly estimate the answer in my head for any given start/target numbers $a$ and $z$. How can I do that?

P.S. I have no background in math, so apologies for awkward wording, incorrect terminology, etc.

Comment: If things improve linearly your average production is $\frac{10 + 65}{2}$ items per month and you want to do this for $12$ months, so the answer is $\frac{75}{2} \cdot 12 = 75 \cdot 6 = 150 \cdot 3 = 450$. This works more generally for any sum of an arithmetic series as in Siong Thye Goh's answer. Various sources will state the answer in a way that looks much uglier than this.

Comment: There's a minor problem with the formula you state in your question. If you start with 1, then the first month will produce $10+5(1) = 15$ items, and your last month will produce $10+5(12) = 70$ items. You either want *n* to range from 0 to 11, OR for the formula to be 10+5(n-1), but not both.

Comment: Thank you @QiaochuYuan, that's extremely intuitive. And nice catch, @ GreyMatters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as [arithmetic series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticSeries.html).

If we start from $a$ and ends with $z$ in $N$ period, the formula is just

$$\frac{N}{2}(a+z).$$

The idea is to pair up the $i$-th number with the $(N-i)$-th number and we notice that the sum is equal for all $i$.

Comment: So in OP's case for months the trick is to add the production of January and December, and multiply by 6.

Comment: For OP, here's an excellent article for building intuition about arithmetic series: https://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/